# Relationship between parameters in graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am quite sure that there is such constant c and I think it's 2 (or smaller?), but I am unable to prove it.

edit: avg(G) means average distance in graph G

Comment: There are many things that can be averaged on a graph: path length, vertex degree, etc. Please give your definition of "avg$(G)$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$\operatorname{avg}(G) = \frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum_{v_1<v_2}\operatorname{dist}(v_1,v_2),$$ then your claim is false unless $c$ depends on the graph (i.e. is not a constant).

Let $G$ be a path of length $k-1$ with $k'=(n-k)$ sized star at one of the ends. Then the diameter of the graph is $\Omega(k)$, but

\begin{align}
\operatorname{avg}(G) &=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\left(\text{star-star}+\text{star-path}+\text{path-path}\right)\\
&= \frac{2}{n(n-1)}\left(O(k'^2) + O(k'\cdot k^2) + O(k^3)\right)\\
&= O(1) \text{ for }k\in O(\sqrt{n})
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @LookingForKnowledge You take two parameters $n$ and $k$ and build a graph. If $k\in O(\sqrt{n})$ and $k\in\omega(1)$ (it has to be greater than a constant), then this graph is a counterexample of size $n$ to your claim. The distance between any pair of the vertices inside the star is $2$, so the sum is bounded by a constant times number of pairs.

Comment: @LookingForKnowledge Yes, there are $k$ vertices in the path and another $n-k$ connected directly to one of the ends.